# Installing Linux based Virtual Machine in Azure Portal

Tags: virtualization, azure

Can i install Linux directly on Host Azure VM instead of installing in hyper-v of Azure VM? As far as i know, Azure VM comes with windows server OS by default, so how to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Azure VM ?

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask Azure support. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/

Answer (score 1):

You can start an Ubuntu instance on Azure without using a Windows VM.

For example, to start a VM running Ubuntu Server 22.04 you can use this offer:

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-gb/marketplace/apps/canonical.0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy?tab=Overview